# Использование с++ объекта в qml : reference error

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Устанавливаю объект в контекст:

```
....
QQmlContext * context = new QQmlContext(engine.rootContext());
context->setContextProperty("data", &data);
QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl(strQmlPath));
....
```

Но при использовании в qml почему то выдает ошибку `reference error: data is not defined`:

```
Item {
    Connections {
        target: data
        onNewMessagePosted: window.visible = false
    }
}
```

Как правильно протолкнуть c++ объект в `qml`?

**UPD:**
сам класс простейший пример

```
class MessageBoard : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public: void callMe () {
        emit newMessagePosted ();
    } ;

    signals: void newMessagePosted ();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
...
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("data", &data);
...
```

И я бы не стал использовать имя *data*, оно много где в Qml используется.

Comment: Сработало!!! Ура!!! имя это пока в качестве примера. Но приму на заметку ;)